# Passing MSBuild Parameters to Web.config XDT Transformation

Tags: msbuild

I need to pass some parameters which should be used during XDT Transformation of my Web Application projects.

Creating multiple Web.(configuration).config is not enough for me.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the Detokenise task (from the MSBuild Extension pack http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/).

This would allow you to perform some token replacement in your config transformation files (web.[configuration].config) prior to running the Transform task.